# Python Django "and/or" searching in database

Tags: python, django, search, checkbox

I have a database set up and I want to have the search engine set so that it will ignore empty fields while searching for everything that's entered into the different search fields. Right now I'm using a combination of AND statements (",") and OR statements ("|") but I'm not sure how to write it to ignore empty checkboxes and text values but only do searches for filled checkboxes and text boxes that are filled in. My search code in my views.py is:

```
incidents = Incident.objects.filter(
                                        Q(datepicker__range=[date_start, date_end]), 
                                        Q(country__contains=country), 
                                        Q(city__contains=city) 
                                        | Q(state__contains=state) 
                                        | Q(province__contains=province) 
                                        | Q(used_firearm__contains=firearm)
                                        | Q(used_taser__contains=taser)
                                        | Q(used_teargas__contains=teargas)
                                        | Q(victim_1_name__contains=victim_name)
                                        | Q(victim_1_ethnicity__contains=victim_ethnicity)
                                        | Q(victim_1_age__contains=victim_age)
                                        | Q(victim_1_sex__contains=victim_sex)
                                        | Q(victim_1_status__contains=victim_status)
                                        | Q(victim_1_armed__contains=victim_armed)
                                        )
```

The datepicker range and country are required, then everything else is an OR statement. For example, if the country is USA then I would want it to search by state, but if the country is Canada, I want it to search by Province. I want it to ignore both if neither are filled in.

Right now, for example, if I choose a start date and an end date, have the country be USA and choose a victim_1_name, it will just return everything in the date range, regardless of name. How would I get it to ignore blank fields, while using AND connectors for the fields that are filled in?

Also, things like "used_firearm" and "used_taser" are checkboxes, my views.py for reading those fields is:

```
if request.POST.get('used_teargas', False):
                teargas             = request.POST['used_teargas']
```

Is that sufficient for having it ignore the checkbox if it's empty, while passing a "True" value through if it's checked?

Comment: You should look into using a proper search engine, like [solr](http://lucene.apache.org/solr/)

Comment: construct your search options in a list before passing them to the filter object so that you only apply the set options.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe something like this:

```
text_fields = {
    'city': request.POST.get('city'),
    'state': request.POST.get('state'),
    'province': request.POST.get('province'),
    'used_teargas': request.POST.get('teargas'),
    'victim_1_name': request.POST.get('victim_name'),
    'victim_1_ethnicity': request.POST.get('victim_ethnicity'),
    'victim_1_age': request.POST.get('victim_age'),
    'victim_1_sex': request.POST.get('victim_sex'),
    'victim_1_status': request.POST.get('victim_status'),
}

boolean_fields = {
    'used_taser': request.POST.get('taser'),
    'used_teargas': request.POST.get('teargas'),
    'victim_1_armed': request.POST.get('victim_armed')
}

q_objects = Q()

for field, value in text_fields.iteritems():
    if value:
        q_objects |= Q(**{field+'__contains': value})

for field, value in boolean_fields.iteritems():
    if value:
        q_objects |= Q(**{field: True})

incidents = Incident.objects.filter(
    Q(datepicker__range=[date_start, date_end]), 
    Q(country__contains=country), 
    q_objects
)
```

The resulting query is very similar to the one you provided, the only difference is the list or `or`ed (`|`) `Q` objects (named `q_objects` here)  is built dynamically - that allows you to provided rules for whether a particular field should be included on that list ("`if value`" in that particular case. That will do exactly what you want - filter out empty strings, `False` values, and `None` values).

You should also look into dedicated search solutions like [Haystack](http://haystacksearch.org/).

Comment: Thanks for the help! This was way shorter than what I'd written. I do plan on looking into the Haystack and Solr search addons, I just want to write something myself so I understand how they work. One question, though - this works on everything but my checkboxes. I have them set as BooleanFields in models, but when I choose one in the search field it has no effect. All the other search fields work, though. Do I need to tell it to look for a different value for checkboxes?

Comment: I added an example of using `bool()` to make sure you get a logical value.

Comment: Hmm I'm confused, it's still not working. Would the bool(request.POST.get('victim_armed')) return a value that I would want to use in Q(**{field+'__contains': value}) or would I want to use something like Q(**{field+'__isnull': value}) ? When I check my sqlite database it tells me that checkbox values are saved as 0 or 1, but when I put {{incident.victim_armed}} in my template, it prints either True or False. Should I be using a separate Q search for checkboxes or do I have a deeper problem with my models? Checkbox HTML is <input type="checkbox" name="victim_armed" id="victim_armed" />

Comment: Going over it, it looks like it might be an issue with the database model. My models.py had victim_armed = models.BooleanField() and my incident create page has {{form.victim_armed}} as the checkbox creator. The only values I was sending was 'on' or null. Should I change the model to victim_armed = models.BooleanField(default=False) in order to make sure there's data in that column so it's searchable? Or am I just using the wrong search terms for checkboxes? Would adding a value to the checkbox HTML fix this? Or adding a value in views.py?

Comment: We can't use `__contains` for BooleanFields. I updated the post.

Comment: That did it, thanks! It was the Q(**{field: True}) that I was struggling with.